# Execute a function only once and when the State is activate

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to understand better a tamplate script for pygame that I'm working with it, but I'm having a doubt: as soon I launch the main.py file in my console is printed "first screen start", but shouldn't it be printed only when the state machine change to `First`? In this way it seems like every state is execute as soon my code start, is this a right way to create a game? Wouldn't this be a problem when my game start to be more complex and articulate? Or should I move my `print_something_one_time` function somewhere else? Because I need for it to be execute only once and only when the state is activate, not as soon the `Splash` screen is shown.
This is my code split in different file: game.py, main.py, base.py and then my states: splash.py and first.py

game.py file:

```
import pygame

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, screen, states, start_state):
        self.done = False
        self.screen = screen
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 30
        self.states = states
        self.state_name = start_state
        self.state = self.states[self.state_name]

    def event_loop(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            self.state.get_event(event)

    def flip_state(self):
        current_state = self.state_name
        next_state = self.state.next_state
        self.state.done = False
        self.state_name = next_state
        persistent = self.state.persist
        self.state = self.states[self.state_name]
        self.state.startup(persistent)

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.state.quit:
            self.done = True
        elif self.state.done:
            self.flip_state()
        self.state.update(dt)

    def draw(self):
        self.state.draw(self.screen)

    def run(self):
        while not self.done:
            dt = self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            self.event_loop()
            self.update(dt)
            self.draw()
            pygame.display.update()
```

main.py file

```
import pygame
import sys

from data.states.splash import Splash
from data.states.first import First
from game import Game


pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

states = {
    "SPLASH": Splash(),
    "FIRST": First(),
}

game = Game(screen, states, "SPLASH")
game.run()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

base.py

```
import pygame


class BaseState(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.done = False
        self.quit = False
        self.next_state = None
        self.screen_rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.persist = {}
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)

    def startup(self, persistent):
        self.persist = persistent

    def get_event(self, event):
        pass

    def update(self, dt):
        pass

    def draw(self, surface):
        pass
```

splash.py

```
import pygame
from .base import BaseState

class Splash(BaseState):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Splash, self).__init__()
        self.title = self.font.render(
            "SPLASH STATE", True, pygame.Color((227, 227, 227))
        )
        self.title_rect = self.title.get_rect(center=self.screen_rect.center)
        self.next_state = "FIRST"
        self.time_active = 0

    def update(self, dt):
        self.time_active += dt
        if self.time_active >= 3000:
            self.done = True

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
        surface.blit(self.title, self.title_rect)
```

first.py

```
import pygame
from .base import BaseState


class First(BaseState):
    def __init__(self):
        super(First, self).__init__()
        self.title = self.font.render(
            "This is the first screen",
            True,
            pygame.Color((227, 227, 227)),
        )
        self.title_rect = self.title.get_rect(center=self.screen_rect.center)
        self.time_active = 0

        self.print_something_one_time()

    def get_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            self.quit = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                self.quit = True

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.fill(pygame.Color("black"))
        surface.blit(self.title, self.title_rect)

    def print_something_one_time(self):
        print("first screen start")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `first screen start` text is printed immediately because the `print_something_one_time` function is called from `__init__`, and you create the `First` instance before entering the main loop here:

```
states = {
    "SPLASH": Splash(),
    "FIRST": First(),
}
```

---

It seems like you already created a function that is called when flipping to another state: `startup`.

So if you want code to run when a state becomes the active state, you should probably put it in there.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've create a startup function in the first.py file and it worked, now the print_something_one_time function start when the state is activeted. I've just one last doubt remaining:  what is the persistent argument? Should I use it and how? Once again, really thank you!

Comment: It seems like it should be used for state that, well, persists through all state changes. For example, let's say you have a state `Gameplay` where you score points. That could be stored inside the `GamePlay` class via `self.persist['score']`. Then when you switch to another state, let's call it `GameOver`, you can access the points the player earned easily via `self.persist['score']`. It's a way to share data between the states.